# display only summary messages in JQuery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have written following code to display the validation error messages. Below code displays both summary as well as inline messages.

Is it possible to display only summary messages?

```
<script>
    var submitted = false;

    $("#myform").validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        },
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            if (submitted) {
                var summary = "You have the following errors: <br/>";
                $.each(errorList, function() { 
                    summary += " * " + this.message + "<br/>"; 
                });
                $("#mydiv").html(summary);
                submitted = false;
            }
            this.defaultShowErrors();
        },          
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            submitted = true;
        },
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Please enter name"
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove below line of code :

```
this.defaultShowErrors();
```

Working fiddle to show only [summary message](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/qhb4Luv0/2/).

Comment: In my existing code, code was removing error messages automatically upon inputting the valid values. But with this, summary is not updating. Am I missing anything?

Comment: No you need to find error message on key up based on index and remove it using find from  error message summary.